# How do I communicate with Google Music All Access when they're wrong about a search result?

Tags: google-play-music

When I perform a search, sometimes I get bad or confused results.  For example, it doesn't seem to distinguish between French artist [Tété](http://www.tete.tt/) and KPOP artist [TeTe](http://www.jpopasia.com/celebrity/tete/).  The same goes for Christian band [Reilly](http://www.reillytheband.com/) and Milwaukee celtic rock band [Reilly](http://www.reillyrocks.com/).

What's the best way to communicate issues such as these?

Answer (score 2):

This has been a problem with Google music for a while, even before All Access. I purchased what appeared to be an album by the band LUSH but was some orchestral compilation or something. Since I bought it, there was a way to complain and reverse the purchase, but the problem with mixing bands continued. I just now searched for LUSH and it looks like the two artists are now separated. So a solution exists, but how best to get it applied is still a mystery, at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can find is a submenu on the support site that asks for support about listening to music on Google Play on the web:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/#contact=1&ts=3006676,3013991,3039144

I've contacted Google Support using this link, and if they share anything with me that is helpful, I'll share it here.

EDIT: I received a reply from customer support:

> Thank you for contacting Google Play Support, I see you have concerns
>   regarding content being incorrectly matched with similar named bands.
>   I understand how upsetting this must be. I assure you I will do my
>   best to assist you today. Thanks for taking the time to report this
>   issue with Google Play's music content. This information will be
>   passed along to our content quality team, who will make any necessary
>   corrections. Please note that this may take some time, since we must
>   communicate with music labels to correct the content. We appreciate
>   your patience.

Apparently, there is a content quality team, and they do want this information, even if it difficult to communicate with them.  As of this writing (June 24, 2013), the aforementioned problems for Tété and Reilly still exist in the search results.